# pylint argues about ternary operator with assignment expression

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint, python-3.8

I have some code like this:

```
return (
    (1 / a)
    if (a := foo())
    else 0
)
```

My pylint argues about this because "Using variable 'a' before assignment", even the evaluation order should be `a := foo()` first and then `1 / a` or `0`. I tried `pip install --upgrade pylint`, but it seems that pylint still do not agree this.

Comment: Since you already have the lastest ``pylint``, and it does not pass this, why do you wonder whether the lastest version should pass this? It obviously doesn't.

Comment: Note that there is no need for out-of-order assignment, ``(a := foo()) and (1 / a)`` should work just as well.

Comment: My bad, the last sentence is wrote before the `pip` sentence and I forget to remove it. Anyway, `(a := foo()) and (1 / a)` is a good solution, but only for `else 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I find that this is an issue of Pylint:

https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3347

"pylint can parse the walrus operator but we haven't actually implemented support for it." (21 Jan)

Anyway, I will modify the code to some equivalent versions which do not cause "Using variable before assignment", for example:

```
if (a := foo()):
    return 1 / a
else:
    return 0
```